# How to replace files whose file extensions doesn't match?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have almost the same problem that was discussed at this article:

[copy 100 new files from one directory and replace each file with the old files in their current location](https://superuser.com/q/1243754/1151788)

I have a 1000 video files in one directory. These are new videos that need to replace old videos that are located in many sub directories. Their basenames match but their extensions don't. In the 'old' folder I have '.MPG' files located in many subdirectories and in the 'new' one I have '.mp4' files in one directory. In both I have video files with the same base name. How could I do that?

What I've written at PowerShell (in oldfolder there are 300 different subdirectories):

```
$newFiles = "C:\newfolder"
$oldFiles = "C:\oldfolder"

Get-ChildItem $newFiles | ForEach-Object {

    $currentFile = $_

    $oldFileLocation = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $oldFiles | Where-Object { $_ -Match "$currentFile"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName

    if($oldFileLocation) {   # if this variable is not null, we've found original file location
        Write-Host "found file [$currentFile] in location: [$oldFileLocation]. overwriting the original."
        Copy-Item -Path $newFiles\$currentFile -Destination $oldFileLocation -Force
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "could not find file [$currentFile] in location [$oldFiles]."
    }

}
```

Then I've run the code and the error message is:

```
WARNING: could not find file [M2U00386.mp4] in location [C:\oldfolder].
WARNING: could not find file [M2U00387.mp4] in location [C:\oldfolder].
WARNING: could not find file [M2U00388.mp4] in location [C:\oldfolder].
WARNING: could not find file [M2U00389.mp4] in location [C:\oldfolder].
.
.
. # and so on because it would find them if the new files were M2U00386.MPG not .mp4.
```

That's produced because file extension doesn't match even though basename does, so my question is: what do I have to change in the first code so that PowerShell doesn't care about file extension ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add to question: What OS? OS tag. Remove windows-explorer and file-transfer tag. You can not make .mp4 files by renaming .mpg files. [Read](https://www.google.com/search?&q=windows+10+BATCH+ffmpeg+.mpg+to+.mp4) and add non-working code to your question.

Comment: I don't want to create .mp4 files by renaming anything. I have two directories: one with .mp4 files and another one with .mpg files, whose basenames are the same but their extensions don't. What I want to do is to replace .mpg files with .mp4 files with the same name, as it was done in the post I linked.

Comment: why replace .mpg? why not delete them?

Comment: Because .mpg files are dispersed in many subdirectories (over 300) inside the 'old folder' and the 'new folde'r is just one folder with all the new files together. And I want the new files went to the places that the old ones were.

Comment: Do you want to copy or move .mp4? Do you want to keep .mpg?

Comment: You want to copy .mpg metadata to .mp4?

Comment: I want to overwrite .mpg by .mp4 and if it were possible, to copy .mpg metadata to .mp4 before .mpg is overwritten.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105767/discussion-between-somebadhat-and-galgarabel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
$newFiles = 'C:\newfolder'
$oldFiles =  'C:\oldfolder'

$oldHash = @{}
Get-ChildItem $oldFIles -File -Recurse | ForEach{
    $oldHash.Add($_.BaseName, $_.DirectoryName)
}

Get-ChildItem $newFiles | ForEach{
    If ($_.BaseName -in $oldHash.Keys) {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName  $oldHash[$_.BaseName]
    } Else {
        echo ('No match found for "{0}".' -f $_.Name)
    }
}
```

It's easy enough to change copy to move & add deletion of old files, but I saw neitehr in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Window 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

Move files based on `$_.basename` Look through every `"C:\oldfolder"` for `.mpg`.  If true, and `$mp4base` equals `$mpgbase`, move-item `$mp4` to `$mpgdir`, remove-item `$mpg` and loop until there are no `$mpg`. **For testing clear your desktop. There should be no directories named `mp4` or `mpg` on your desktop.**

```
pushd $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop;ni -itemtype directory "mp4", "mpg\mpg2">$null;foreach($i in 1..20){ni -itemtype file "mp4\$i.mp4">$null };foreach($i in 1..10){ni -itemtype file "mpg\$i.mpg">$null };foreach($i in 11..20){ni -itemtype file "mpg\mpg2\$i.mpg">$null };popd;
$Files = @(Get-ChildItem .\mpg\*.mpg -recurse)
if (!($Files.length -eq 0)) {
Get-ChildItem mp4 | ForEach-Object { 
    $mp4= $_.fullname
    $mp4base= $_.basename
Get-ChildItem mpg -recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $mpg = $_.fullname
    $mpgbase= $_.basename
    $mpgdir= $_.directoryname
    if ($mp4base -eq $mpgbase) {
    move-item $mp4 $mpgdir
    remove-item $mpg
    }
}} 
explorer .\mpg;cls 
Read-Host "    
Press enter key to delete all test files"
ri (".\mpg", ".\mp4") -recurse -force 
#
popd 
#    
} else {write-host "   No .mpg to process." }
#
```